# Trying to make a minecraft datapack, but I get a parse error

Tags: json, minecraft

```
    "type": "origins:active_self",
    "entity_action": {
        "type": "origins:and",
        "actions": [
            {
                "type": "origins:clear_effect",
                "effect": "minecraft:poison"
            },
            {
                "type": "origins:apply_effect",
                "effect": {
                    "effect": "minecraft:resistance",
                    "duration": 200,
                    "amplifier": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "origins:apply_effect",
                                  "effect": {
                    "effect": "minecraft:strength",
                    "duration": 200,
                    "amplifier": 2          
                   },
            
    },
    "cooldown": 600,
    "hud_render": {
        "should_render": true,
        "sprite_location": "origins:textures/gui/community/spiderkolo/resource_bar_02.png",
        "bar_index": 0
    },
    "key": {
        "key": "key.origins.primary_active",
        "continuous": false
    },
    "name": "Hunter to hunted",
    "description": "Once activated, any effects on the player (such as poison) will be cleared and they will get resistance II and strength II (Primary)"
}
```

### What am I doing wrong here?
parser says
Error: Parse error on line 23:
...fier": 2             },          },          "cooldown": 60

Expecting 'STRING', got '}'
How do I fix this
I am very new to these things

Comment: A useful trick here is to count brackets: start at the top of the file; every time you see an open bracket, count up one; every time you see a close bracket, count down one; you should get back to zero. If you get to zero too soon, you're missing an opening bracket; if you never get to zero, you're missing a closing bracket. The other trick is to make sure the indentation matches the bracket - every block that's indented should have a matching pair of brackets above and below it. You can also use a programmer's editor or IDE which will have features for doing that kind of thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "type": "origins:active_self",
  "entity_action": {
    "type": "origins:and",
    "actions": [
      {
        "type": "origins:clear_effect",
        "effect": "minecraft:poison"
      },
      {
        "type": "origins:apply_effect",
        "effect": {
          "effect": "minecraft:resistance",
          "duration": 200,
          "amplifier": 2
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "origins:apply_effect",
        "effect": {
          "effect": "minecraft:strength",
          "duration": 200,
          "amplifier": 2
        }
      }
    ],  <--- You missed a back here
    "cooldown": 600,
    "hud_render": {
      "should_render": true,
      "sprite_location": "origins:textures/gui/community/spiderkolo/resource_bar_02.png",
      "bar_index": 0
    },
    "key": {
      "key": "key.origins.primary_active",
      "continuous": false
    },
    "name": "Hunter to hunted",
    "description": "Once activated, any effects on the player (such as poison) will be cleared and they will get resistance II and strength II (Primary)"
  }
}
```

As you see, the value of `actions` is a list. You look through the lines and won't find the `]`.